# How to get the highest and lowest result per ID passed in WHERE IN

Tags: mysql

I'm using an ORM and I need to get posts and their highest and lowest rated comment. The ORM executes the next query to get all comments for the posts I queried:

```sql
select * 
from `comments` 
where `comments`.`post_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4) 
order by `rating` desc
```

Currently, I filter the comments manually in the app.

How can I change this query to return only 2 comments per post - the highest rated (MAX(rating)) and lowest rated (MIN(rating)) comments on the post? Every post has at least 2 comments.

Answer (score 1):

First with `group by` get the min and max ratings of each comment and then join to the table:

```
select c.*
  from comments c inner join ( 
  select post_id, min(rating) minrating, max(rating) maxrating
  from comments
  group by post_id
) g on g.post_id = c.post_id and c.rating in (g.minrating, g.maxrating)
```

If there are comments with equal rating, they will all be returned.

Comment: Hmm that seems promising. Will test it in a few hours and get back to you. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post_id,MAX(rating) as highest_rated, MIN(rating) AS lowest_rated
FROM comments
WHERE post_id IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY post_id
```

Comment: The OP wants corresponding comments as well. This query won't solve for that